# d3js voronoi Map for india

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, maps, voronoi

I want to make a maps of India similar to this [example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html). I have polygon coordinates of India and I can project map of india, but how can I load this csv data to maps and make look like the demo.

I have a csv file that looks like that:

```
Name,   Latitude,   Longitude
Data-5538,  27.471267,  94.913609
Data-5538,  27.477969,  94.952577
Data-5538,  27.494111,  94.933865
Data-5538,  27.449333,  94.889062
```